# How to list the files inside a docker image without running it as a container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image where I have forgotten what the start command is.   This is a stripped down container without any shell, so I can't just run it temporarily as a `sh/bash` container and do an `ls`.

How do I see the files inside this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

`docker history --no-trunc your_image`

it should show you as first command the start command.